# Tag editing bumps questions

Tags: discussion, edits, bump

I have seen a situation where a great number of questions were being bumped to the top of the active queue as they were being edited by one person one after the other.

The reason for the edits was to link multiple questions to relevant new tags and remove incorrect tags, which was a good idea to me, but the problem with doing this is the fact that this bumps the questions to the top of the 'active' queue which everyone lands on by default when arriving on the site.  Therefore any new questions get pushed down the queue with the risk of being lost amongst the old questions.

Should edits which are just **tag edits** result in the question having their active status changed?